# warning: unhandled dyld version (17) gdb

Tags: c, gdb, homebrew

I have just finished code-signing and setting up gdb on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 . I am receiving this error: `warning: unhandled dyld version (17)`. Upon running my very simple "Hello world" program in gdb:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    printf("hello world!\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have found information related to the `unhandled dyld version (15)` but not this error. I am running gdb version 12.1, installed with homebrew.

It also runs forever until I keyboard interrupt `^C` and then it exits and sends output to the screen.

Edit:

build `gcc -g hello.c` run `gdb a.out`, reads debug from `a.out.dSYM`

Comment: How do you *build* it before running?

Comment: `gcc -g hello.c` and then run `gdb a.out`, reads symbols from `a.out.dSYM`

Comment: Same issue here.  The best answer I've found so far is to use "lldb" in place of gdb